# boost shared_ptr and 'this'

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

I have two classes with a parent-child relationship (customer&order directory&file etc)

I have

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr<Parent> ParentPtr
```

and in parent class a method to make a child

I need child instances to have pointers to their parent.

```
class Child
{
 ....
     ParentPtr m_parent;
 ....
}
```

I want it to be a shared_ptr so that the parent doesn't disappear while there are existing children. I also have other people holding ParentPtrs to the parent (the factory method for Parents returns a ParentPtr)

Question: how can give the child a ParentPtr

attempt (1) . In Parent::ChildFactory

```
child->m_parent.reset(this);
```

this results in very bad things. There are now 2 ParentPtr 'chains' pointing at the parent; result is premature death of Parent

attempt (2). Parent has

```
ParentPtr m_me;
```

which is copied from the return value of the Parent factory. So I can do

```
child->m_parent = m_me;
```

But now Parent never dies because it holds a reference to itself

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm fairly sure that `enable_shared_from_this` solves your problem: http://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/smart_ptr/enable_shared_from_this.html

If you derived your class from a specialization of `boost::enable_shared_from_this` then you can use `shared_from_this()` in a member function to obtain the shared pointer that owns `this` (assuming that there is one).

E.g.

```
class Parent : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<Parent>
{
    void MakeParentOf(Child& c)
    {
        c.m_parent = shared_from_this();
    }
};
```

Comment: @pm100: Why do you need to use a `weak_ptr`? If the children own their parents (shared betweem them) then you need to use a `shared_ptr`. A `weak_ptr` does not imply ownership.

Comment: oh yes you are correct - I was thinking of a different solution - removing edit

Comment: i could have had the parent have a weak pointer to itself that it could use to generate the shared_ptr that it could pass to children (like my m_me), but the enable_share makes this not necessary (I suspect thats what it does under the hood)

Answer (score 0):

As the other response has pointer out, first you'll have to use the `enable_shared_from_this` to get the `shared_ptr`, but then the child *can't* hold that ref, it *must* use a `weak_ptr`.  A `weak_ptr` is just like a `shared_ptr` except that it won't hold a reference until you call the `get()` method, which will return you a normal `shared_ptr` which you should get rid of as soon as you can inside the child.

Comment: Why do you think this? The model is that the children (together with "other people") own their parents; the parents don't own the children. If the children use a weak pointer then it won't prevent the parents from "disappearing" while they still have children in existence.

Comment: @Charles Sorry, my bad.  I'm assuming things that weren't explicitly mentioned: I assumed that if `shared_ptr` and `weak_ptr` were used, parents were going to have ref's to their children.  I assumed that, just because, by default, parents control their children, until at least they turn 18 and leave home.  If it is the other way round, please ignore everything I said.

Comment: Well, I don't know exactly what the structure of pm100's code is but I was reasoning that if he is concerned about parents being destroyed while they still had children then the parent class couldn't own (either directly by value or via a `shared_ptr`) the child classes otherwise it wouldn't even be a consideration. The ownership relationship would ensure that a child couldn't outlive its last parent. As it is, it's my understanding that the required ownership is the other way around: "I want it to be a shared_ptr so that the parent doesn't disappear while there are existing children."

Comment: Well, I guess it depends on what the code is like, but anyway, between us, we gave all that he might need, one way or the other. ;-)